# Replace last but one occurance of space with comma in python

Tags: python, replace

I have this *string* below. How can I replace the last but one space without using a for loop in python.

> `"814409014860", "BOA ", "604938XXXXXX5410 ",,"ADOM ","ADU SAVBOSS SVGIDIIADOM0001 Int. charge ","24/05/18 09:39:08 0.70 ",0.00`

I want to avoid for loop because the the data is huge.

The comma is needed just after the minutes timestamp

> `09:39:08 0.70 ",0.00` => `09:39:08, 0.70 ",0.00`

Python, bash, c# is preferred.

Comment: Let me clarify your question: you want to replace `space`-symbol only after "0.70 " preserving all other: "24/05/18 09:39:08 ", "Int. charge ". Yes?

Comment: And "huge": "huge" as "cannot fit in RAM (or near to this)", "huge" as "..." ?

Comment: No, before `0.70`

Comment: Actually, it would take quite longer. Thats the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [rfind](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) and `rsplit`:

```
# First find the occurrence of the last space
last_space_index = big_string.rfind(" ")

# then split from the right the substring that ends in that index
new_big_string = ", ".join(big_string[:last_space_index].rsplit(" ", 1)) + big_string[last_space_index:]
```

Comment: Be careful: It seems that last occurrence is not the last

Comment: The OP need to replace the "last but one" occurrence, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry! English is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 1):

Python regex substitution?

```
import re

s = '"814409014860", "BOA ", "604938XXXXXX5410 ",,"ADOM ","ADU SAVBOSS SVGIDIIADOM0001 Int. charge ","24/05/18 09:39:08 0.70 ",0.00'

pattern = r'(\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})'

output = re.sub(pattern,r'\1,',s)

print(output)

>'"814409014860", "BOA ", "604938XXXXXX5410 ",,"ADOM ","ADU SAVBOSS SVGIDIIADOM0001 Int. charge ","24/05/18 09:39:08, 0.70 ",0.00'
```

Comment: Locates the timestamp pattern `r'(\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})'` and replaces it with the matched pattern with a comma after `r'\1,'`.